# Will Paginate Pagination link range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, will-paginate

i am using **will_paginate** for my rails3 project.
i have small width for showing the pagination range links result.

i'm showing > 100 records, 8 per page.
so the will_paginate links appear as **1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, .... 14,15**
which goes beyond my available width.

i want to show them may be from 1 to 5 then ... last two pages. ( 1,2,3,4,5, .... 14 ,15 )
Will_Paginate does not take any parameters for doing such thing.

Have anyone tried overriding / tweaking such methods for doing so ??
Or suggestion for any other pagination that has the above options are welcomed!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do it using option for will_paginate, something like :

```
will_paginate @collections, :inner_window => 2, :outer_window => 2
```

See  [documention of will_paginate](http://rubydoc.info/gems/will_paginate/2.3.15/WillPaginate/ViewHelpers%3awill_paginate)